# How to restrict visibility of account to an opportunity owner?

Tags: opportunity, security, account, sharing, ownership

Transferring ownership of an account is quite common in the company.
If we change the owner of an account, for historical reason, the opportunity owner should be maintain, and that's ok we can do that.

However from a Salesforce point of view, if you are the owner of the opportunity, you can automatically see the account, it's called ***Associated record owner or sharing***. That's an issue for us.

I try to delete the sharing manually through the Sharing Screen but I'm getting the following error:

> Sharing cannot be deleted This sharing access cannot be deleted due to
> one of the following reasons:
>
> - The user owns or has manually been granted access to one or more records associated with this account.
> - The group has access to one or more of the contacts, opportunities, or cases on this account due to a sharing rule.
> - The user is a contact on an associated case.
>
> Users and groups must have at least "Read Only" access to any account
> where they own or have sharing access to an associated record (for
> example, contacts, opportunities, or cases)

How can we restrict the visibility of the account in this particular scenario ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't restrict access. It's called [*Implicit Sharing*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm). You'd have to remove the account from the opportunity entirely, or switch the opportunity to a new account. You can read more about it under the [Built-In Sharing Behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_across_objects.htm&language=en_US) help topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought, and I agree with both options. However it wouldn't work because the new owner won't see the old opportunity then, and in terms of reporting you will see that as 2 different entities, not a single account. I guess the business will have to change their politic then.